# Stackoverflow authentication data storage

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, login, auto-login

Maybe this question has been asked, but I couldn't find it with google and stackoverflow.
I have deleted all my cookies and yet after entering stackoverflow.com I'm asked to refresh the page, because I have been logged in.

How does stackoverflow.com authentication data storage works?

Comment: Are you still logged in from other services? See [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the link. The answer was `localStorage`. This is how stackoverflow.com knows about me even after I've deleted all browser's cookies.

Comment: Indeed. Now, many browsers delete local storage when deleting cookies. Some have renamed their "delete cookies" option to be more specific about that; Chrome uses "Delete cookies and other site and plug-in data", and Safari uses "Remove all website data". Such options might then even included storage from plugins, most notably Flash LSO.